# Rearrange a string so that letter 'x' is never followed by letter 'y'

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a string, say automatic or auter. And I want to ensure that if the letter 'u' follows the letter 'a' the characters are reversed.

Say

```
Input: automatic
Output: uatomatic

Input: auter
Output: uater

Input: auauauauauauau
Output:uuuuuuuaaaaaaa
```

Is it possible to this in a single pass?

EDIT: I have a C implementation, but I'm not sure how to reverse the string in place, so that my whole line doesnt getter reversed, just the words.

```
char* characterReverse(char* input) {
    char temp;

    int low = 0;
    int length = strlen( input );
    int high = length - 1;

    while ( low <= high )
    {
        temp = input[ low ];
        input[ low ] = input[ high ];
        input[ high ] = temp;

        low++;
        high--;
    }

return input;
```

}

Comment: What language are you working in? What have you tried so far to work this out yourself?

Comment: What are the requirements if the 'u' follows the 'a' but with a letter in between? eg 'atu'.

Comment: it might be possible if you start from the end, not from the beginning of the string

Comment: @AndrewShepherd for the sake of simplicity lets say this case is ignored for now.

Comment: You need to increment `low` until you find an `a` and decrement `high` until you find a `u`, and then swap.

Comment: Pretend your A/U debacle is a need to "sort" them, check out http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/ are any of those single pass sorting algos?  Can you re-use them and think of your data as sorted once it meets your criteria ;)

Comment: @liquid For clarification, `axu` should go to `uxa` ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a C# implementation that works with your test cases (note that it only works with lowercase. Let me know if you need a case-insensitive version):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input1 = "automatic";
        string input2 = "auter";
        string input3 = "auauauauauauau";

        Console.WriteLine("Input: {0}{2}Output: {1}{2}", input1, ReverseAu(input1), Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine("Input: {0}{2}Output: {1}{2}", input2, ReverseAu(input2), Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine("Input: {0}{2}Output: {1}{2}", input3, ReverseAu(input3), Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private static string ReverseAu(string input)
    {
        char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();

        int ndx = input.IndexOf("au", StringComparison.Ordinal);

        while (ndx > -1)
        {
            chars[ndx] = 'u';
            chars[ndx + 1] = 'a';
            input = new string(chars);
            chars = input.ToCharArray();
            ndx = input.IndexOf("au", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        }

        return input;
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a **single pass** algorithm.

Comment: The OP didn't say single pass was a requirement. He asked if it was possible. I am giving him one way to do it. My way of doing it does meet his requirements.

Comment: This is very clever! I had not thought of getting the index of the character combination that I was searching for, I will see if I can attempt to implement this in a single pass. EDIT: Just read the comment underneath, single pass wasnt a requirement, I just want to see if it can be done, I'll go from here with the algorithm in mind and tweak as needed.

Comment: The edit kind of obscured the question, but the question still remains, "Is it possible to (do) this in a single pass?"

Comment: @user3386109 -- Will think about this and see if I can modify my answer to work with one pass.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about one pass and in-place (that's a bit difficult / impossible because you can't know what character to put at a position without looking ahead), but here's the next best thing - an `O(n)` in-place algorithm: (in Java)

```java
char[] characterReverse(char[] arr, char x, char y)
{
   int xCount = 0, yCount = 0, lastPos = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
   {
      if (arr[i] == x)
         xCount++;
      else if (arr[i] == y && xCount > 0)
         yCount++;
      else
      {
         for (; yCount > 0; yCount--)
            arr[lastPos++] = y;
         for (; xCount > 0; xCount--)
            arr[lastPos++] = x;
         lastPos = i+1;
      }
   }
   for (; yCount > 0; yCount--)
      arr[lastPos++] = y;
   for (; xCount > 0; xCount--)
      arr[lastPos++] = x;
   return arr;
}
```

The basic idea is to, as soon as we see an `x`, keep track of the number of `x` and `y` characters, until we get something else, then to start putting the `y`'s then the `x`'s back from the position where we saw the first `x`.

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/sVRwSk).

Comment: This looks to be one-pass and in place to me.  It is O(n), the writes are delayed with respect to the reads but it doesn't scan the array twice.

Comment: @dave I guess there are multiple ways to define single pass (the significant part here being whether you count writing the output as part of the pass or as a separate pass), but it's a somewhat arbitrary constraint in anyway - an O(n) constraint is more meaningful.